# Keeping information on Form B from Form A when Form A is closed

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I was wondering if there is any code that lets some information you enter on Form A remain in the textboxes in Form B when Form A is closed. Im hoping to keep some user information entered into the first form on the second form and still have the first form close.

Thank you!

Comment: If the two forms are independent of each other, then yes. If it's a subform, then no.

Answer (score 0):

You can't maintain value from field when you close a form. So you can create some Global vars to copy his value and maintain on memory.
Sometimes i use another option: hide the form A meanwhile you use form B, then when you need to close Form B, simply check if A is open and then close it.

```html
Function FIsLoaded(stFrmName$) As Integer
    Dim I As Integer
    For I% = 0 To Forms.Count - 1
        If (Forms(I%).FormName = stFrmName$) Then
            FIsLoaded = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next I%
    For I% = 0 To Reports.Count - 1
        If (Reports(I%).FormName = stFrmName$) Then
            FIsLoaded = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next I%

    FIsLoaded = False

End Function
```

With this function you can do before close form:

```html
if fisloaded("formA") then 
  DoCmd.Close acForm ,"formA"
end if
```

Comment: Is the stFrmName$ the name of Form B? Also what does the reports section do?

Comment: The StFrmName$ is only the value that you send to know if the form is loaded or not. You can call with the second code added: fisloaded("form-youneed"). This function is for Forms or Reports, are the same.